# secure_getenv function not giving the expected result

Tags: c, coding-style, glibc, libc, getenv

In my program I am using secure_getenv function to fetch some environment variables. I included stdlib.h in my program. This is the sample call to secure_getenv.

Line 1 : char *myenv;

Line 2 : myenv = __secure_getenv("DATA");

After the above lines execution, myenv points to some junk.

I tried this within gdb after line 2.

*p __secure_getenv("DATA")*

This prints me the DATA I wanted.

But when I try,
"**p myenv**",
It prints the below.

**$2 = 0×fffffffffffffe13f<Address 0xfffffffffffffe13f out of bounds>"**

Can the experts help me to understand what is missing & how to make this work.

Edited to add:
How the **myenv** is actually used?
In somepoint in time my code tries to call the below.

**strlen(myenv)**;

On strlen function call, my code terminates with sig11(SIGSEGV)

Comment: If you compiled with optimization, the generated code execution sequence does often not correspond to the source code order, so for example a source line has to be visited multiple times in the debugger before it is completely executed. Try to continue to a line where `myenv` is actually used, and print it there.

Comment: Thank you. Just edited my post to add how the myenv is actually used.

Comment: The code presented *does not* use `secure_getenv()`.  It uses `__secure_getenv()`, which I don't think is a documented interface or one intended to be accessed by user code.

Comment: Please present a [mre] demonstrating the issue.  Include the command you're using to compile the program.  Also, pay attention to compiler diagnostics.  Unless you're defining `__secure_getenv` yourself (or not using it after all), or unless you are actively suppressing compiler messages, it is highly unlikely that the compiler is accepting your code without emitting any diagnostics.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I tried replacing __secure_getenv with just getenv and it resulted in the same behavior.

Comment: Again: *minimal reproducible example*.  And compiler diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

> Can the experts help me to understand what is missing & how to make this work.

The most likely cause is that you don't have a prototype for `__secure_getenv`, which means that the compiler *assumes* that this function returns an `int`. That `int` is then cast to `char*`, which sign-extends it to produce "garbage" pointer `0xfffffffffffffe13f`.

1. You should compile your source with `-Wall -Wextra` -- the compiler will then warn you about the bug.
2. You should `#include <stdlib.h>` and use `secure_getenv()` instead of `__secure_getenv()` -- the former will have a proper prototype.
3. You can compare the output from `p __secure_getenv("DATA")` -- it will print the data you expect, and also the pointer value. If my guess is correct, the pointer value will have different high-order bits, but same low 32-bits as `myenv == 0xfffffffffffffe13f`